# Inject controller into App?

Tags: angularjs, coffeescript

I am having difficulties trying to get this piece of code to work. I am trying to follow a tutorial from pluralsight, but wanted to split up the app file, the controller file, and service file into different files. After doing this, my code no longer works. What am I missing to make this work properly?

http://plnkr.co/edit/7Mwb1M2e9KvG8zlIDmEx?p=preview

AppFile:

```
do ->
    app = angular.module("githubViewer", [])
```

Controller File:

```
do ->
  MainController =($scope, github, $interval, $log, $location, $anchorScroll) ->
    vm = this
    vm.username = "angular"
    vm.sortField = "+language"
    vm.message = "Github Viewer"
    vm.countdown = 5

    onUserComplete =(data) ->
      vm.user = data
      github.getRepos.then(onRepos, onError)
      vm.noError = true
      return

    onRepos =(response) ->
      vm.user.repos = response.data
      $location.hash("userDetails")
      $anchorScroll()

    onError =(reason) ->
      vm.message = "Could not fetch user"
      vm.noError = false
      return

    vm.search =() ->
      $log.info("Searching for " + vm.username)
      github.getUser(vm.username).then(onUserComplete, onError)
      if(countdownInterval)
        $interval.cancel(countdownInterval)
        vm.countdown = null
      return

    decrementCountdown =() ->
      vm.countdown -= 1
      if(vm.countdown < 1)
        vm.search()
      return

    countdownInterval = null
    startCountdown =() ->
      countdownInterval = $interval(decrementCountdown, 1000, vm.countdown)
      return

    startCountdown()

    return

  app = angular.module("githubViewer")
  app.controller("MainController", ["$scope", "github", "$interval", 
                 "$log", "$location", "$anchorScroll", MainController])
```

Service File:

```
do ->
  github =($http) ->
    getUser =(username) ->
      return $http.get("https://api.github.com/users/" + username)
                  .then ->
                    return response.data

    getRepos =(user) ->
      return $http.get(vm.user.repos_url)
                  .then ->
                    return response.data

    return {
      getUser: getUser,
      getRepos: getRepos
    }

  app = angular.module("githubViewer")
  app.factory("github", ["$http", github])
  return
```

Comment: I ran the code in the plunker link that you specified, and the code does seem to run - I get "Could not fetch user".

Comment: Previously, with them all the angular code in one file, it was working and it was able to fetch the user properly. And there is an error in the console, saying that response is undefined.

Answer (score 0):

In the service file, there is a reference to vm.user:

```
$http.get(vm.user.repos_url)
```

but vm is not declared or defined in the script.